# Where are my 302 redirects created?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**Can anyone please help?**

Hi Guys,  This is my first post so hopefully I'm using the forum correctly.

A month or so back I installed SSL certificate on our CentOS Digital Ocean Apache server. Yesterday I signed up for a MOZ trial and the crawl report advises that I have 35 pages with a 302 temporary redirect. I'm struggling to find how I can make these permanent redirects.

I’ve checked my .htaccess file and I can’t see any 302 references in it.

Please can anyone help me out?

Some of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https: //www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http: //www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've also looked in httpd.conf. My VirtualHost blocks look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxxxxx@hotmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/public_html
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/mysite/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/mysite/requests.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me with where else should I be looking?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Magneto? Or is your website some type of store? I've seen MOZ show this sort of problem with other people using Magneto.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

produces a 302 status code by default:

> Any valid HTTP response status code may be specified, using the syntax [R=305], with a 302 status code being used by default if none is specified.

Source: [Apache 2.4 docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)

You can change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

and that should produce a 301.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I will change my .htaccess file immediately and initiate a fresh crawl of the website.